# Problem with numerical integration and optim R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I try to optimize a tricky density which involves a combination of integrate and optim in R for some interest parameters. My question is more about code than statistics, that's why I post here.

I made some researchs on Internet and I didn't find anything. So I tried to make some non-convinced tries. I would like to estimate my parameters Beta without b impact.

I've had some differents errors about integrate or optim.
Here a example of what I'm trying to do.

```r
X <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,56,54,32,12,9), nrow=5, ncol=2)
y <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0), nrow=5, ncol=1)


f <- function(beta){
  g <- function(X,y,b){
    (1/(1 + exp(-(X%*%beta + b))))^y - (1-(1/(1 + exp(-(X%*%beta + b)))))^(1-y)
  }
  integrate(Vectorize(g), lower = 0, upper = Inf,X=X, y=y)
}

optim(par=c(1,0), f, method="BFGS", hessian=TRUE)
```

I would like an estimate for my beta parameters with optim package. 
I work on it since 1 week and I'm really struggle to have some estimates for my 2 parameters beta0 and beta1.

Different approaches for this estimation, like EM algorithm or Gauss-Hermite Quadrature are welcome.

Thanks for any help.

Loïc.

Comment: there is something wrong with your eqn. the error message says that you are trying to take the natural log of negative numbers. is there an online resource that shows your eqn?

Comment: I edit my post without log. Log is not really important. I just want to understand how to optimize it properly.

Comment: what is the integration variable of `g` ?

Comment: b, X and y are known Matrix of  covariates and vector to predict respectively.

Comment: @MangnierLoïc What is the meaning of `X%*%beta + b` if `b` is a single number ? Please use "@" to notify a user.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent b in my context is the random intercept in a mixed model. I have some correlation between my covariates and my random effects, that's why I wanna suppress its.

Comment: not obvious what the equation is as this will affects how the order of the arguments in your `g` function which is required for `Vectorize`. Here is an integrand using the example in `?integrate`: `X <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,56,54,32,12,9), nrow=5, ncol=2);
y <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0), nrow=5, ncol=1);


f <- function(b) {
    g <- function(x) 1 / ((x+1)*sqrt(x));
    integrate(g, lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value
}

optim(par=c(1,0), f, method="BFGS", hessian=TRUE);

`